# event observer in magento not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, ce-1.9.1.0

I can't get an observer working, I'm using Magento of 1.9.1.0.

My namespace: pan

My module: Registration

app/etc/modules/pan_Registration.xml:

[image: pan_Registration]

app/code/local/TM/ProductConditions/etc/config.xml:

[image]

Observer.php :

```
<?php

class pan_Registration_Model_Observer 
 {


    public function customerRegisterSuccess($observer) {
        echo "kjdsnfkjsdfknsd";
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $cid = $event->getCustomer();
        echo "kjdsnfkjsdfknsd";
    echo $cid;
    exit;       
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: observer.php : <?php

class pan_Registration_Model_Observer 
 {
  
 
    public function customerRegisterSuccess($observer) {
  echo "kjdsnfkjsdfknsd";
  $event = $observer->getEvent();
  $cid = $event->getCustomer();
  echo "kjdsnfkjsdfknsd";
    echo $cid;
    exit;
           
        
 
    }
}
?>

Answer (score 4):

The module cannot be loaded. In `app/etc/modules/pan_Registration.xml` you specify that the module is found in `app/code/local/pan/Registration`, but you put it in `app/code/local/TM/ProductConditions`.

Additionally a lower case vendor name (*pan*) is against the conventions. I'm actually not sure if it really works, so you should consider changing `pan_Registration` to `Pan_Registration` in the `<modules>` element of both XML files, and move the module files to `app/code/local/Pan/Registration`

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace: pan

First character should be a capital letter like Pan

app/etc/modules/Pan_Registration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pan_Registration>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pan_Registration>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Pan/Registration/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pan_Registration>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pan_Registration>
  </modules>
  <global>    
    <models>
      <registration>
        <class>Pan_Registration_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>registration_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </registration>
    </models>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <customer_register_success_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>registration/observer</class>
            <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
          </customer_register_success_handler>
        </observers>
      </customer_register_success>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Pan/Registration/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Pan_Registration_Model_Observer
{

            public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                //Your code
            }

}
```